# How to modify interface value of type struct pointer

Tags: pointers, go, struct, interface, dereference

So I have some interfaces and structs:

```
type Component interface{}

type Position struct{
    x float64
}

func Main(){
    var components []Components
    components = append(components, &Position{1.0})
    
    pos := components[0] // this is a Component, however reflect.TypeOf() returns *Position

    *pos = Position{2.0} // this won't compile as golang says you can't dereference a 'Component'
}
```

How would I modify the actual value (e.g. change 'x') inside the pos variable one I retrieved it? I am storing these pointers in a Component slice as there are various types that implement components.
I have tried doing this:

```
func Swap(component *Component, value Component){
    *component = value
}
```

however this does not work (it runs however the new value is not udpated). How do I dereference the component and assign its value?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Component interface{}

type Position struct {
    x float64
}

func (p Position) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%f", p.x)
}

func main() {
    components := []Component{&Position{1.0}}
    fmt.Println(components)
    
    pos, ok := components[0].(*Position)
    if !ok {
        panic("Not a *Position")
    }
    pos.x = 1000.0
    fmt.Println(components)
}
```

This prints:

```
[1.000000]
[1000.000000]
```

If you need to check for multiple types, you could use a [type switch](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16).